# Algorithm: Difference between two ordered lists, by order and composition

Tags: algorithm, go, difference

I'm looking for a general algorithm to find a minimum diff between two ordered lists.

I need it in Go, so let's assume they are slices of strings. An example of a list:

```golang
list := []string{
    "Anna",
    "Mike",
    "Simon",
    "Jerry",
    "Louisa",
    "Mary",
}
```

Note that elements in this list are unique.

The second list would be an altered version of this list. Changes may include any of these cases, separately or combined:

- one (or more) of list elements moves one or few positions up or down;
- two elements switch places;
- a new element replaces one of old elements.

What I want as a result of the comparison is a minimal set of changes that need to be applied to the first list to get the second one. I would then use these data to mark changes in the list. For example, I would like to produce such output:

```
Anna
Mike
↑Louisa
Simon
Jerry
Mary
```

This shows that in the new list, "Louisa" has moved up. I would also like to be aware that "Louisa" has moved **2** positions up, but I don't need to show it in my output.

What's important here for me is that positions of "Simon" and "Jerry" have changed too, but the whole difference between lists can be described with only *"Louisa" moving 2 positions up*, and such description is shorter so I see it as minimal and that's what I want to get.

Is there any package that can do the trick, or maybe a known algorithm? If it is of any importance, the length of the list is not going to change in my case.

Comment: Asking for packages is OT. For the algorithm: You looking for a variant of edit distance.

Comment: @Volker Hi! What's OT? And I don't think I need the edit distance "as is" since it usually doesn't provide the edit itself, just the amount of required edits. But could be that the process of calculating edit distance involves what I need. Although, a normal edit distance would rather suggest removing and adding elements instead of moving them around.

Comment: 1. "Is there any package that can do the trick" is asking for third party library which is OT according to the community guidelines on SO. 2. There are different variants of edit distance as you seem to know, depending on which edit  operations are allowed. The technique to find such edit sequences is called "Dynamic Programming" which you might want to look up and adapt to your problem.

Comment: @Helyrk: OT stands for Off Topic - i.e., not something people are supposed to do on StackOverflow. You're right that edit distance alone is not enough, but you need an algorithm to find an edit that also includes moves. Edit-with-moves is tricky, but [here](http://dimacs.rutgers.edu/~graham/pubs/papers/editmovestalg.pdf) is a Rutgers paper from 2006.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Volker** and **torek**, thank you for your comments, I find them to be the most relevant to the question. Apologies for the off-topic, I don't have much experience asking on StackOverflow yet.

The article referenced by **torek** is focusing on designing an algorithm with the highest achievable efficiency. It is indeed a great achievement but in my particular application, I'm going to use this algorithm for lists containing only 10 items and only once in a few hours, so I don't need it to have a top-notch efficiency. Thus, I got a rather simple idea of how to do it and it seems to work.

The idea is to calculate a difference between new and old positions of all elements, find the element with the largest shift, mark how it shifted in a report for the output, and move it to its new position. Then repeat it until lists are identical. Differences in composition of the lists should be addressed before this operation. I can't guarantee that it will work completely as expected on big lists with many differences between them, but I will need it for relatively short lists with only 1-2 changes so it should work for me.

Here's an example code:

```golang
// diff describes how an updated position of an element is different from an old one
// it's either a new element, or it's shifted by "shift" in "direction", or position didn't change
type diff struct {
    shift int
    direction direction
    isNew bool
}

type direction int
const (
    up = direction(-1)
    down = direction(1)
    none = direction(0)
)

func hasShifts(shifts []diff) bool {
    for _, d := range shifts {
        if d.shift != 0 {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}

func diffs(old, updated []string) (shifts []diff) {
    for i, newEl := range updated {
        for j, oldEl := range old {
            if newEl == oldEl {
                var dir direction
                switch {
                case i < j:
                    dir = up
                case i > j:
                    dir = down
                default:
                    dir = none
                }
                shifts = append(shifts, diff{int(math.Abs(float64(i-j))), dir, false})
                break
            }
        }
        if len(shifts) < i+1 {
            shifts = append(shifts, diff{isNew: true})
        }
    }
    return
}

func move(list *[]string, position, shift int, dir direction) {
    for i := position; i != position + shift * int(dir); i += int(dir) {
        (*list)[i], (*list)[i+int(dir)] = (*list)[i+int(dir)], (*list)[i]
    }
}

func compare(old, updated []string) (report []string) {
    report = append([]string{}, updated...)

    // first, find and mark updated elements; add them to the old list
    shifts := diffs(old, updated)
    for i, d := range shifts {
        if d.isNew {
            old = append(old[:i], append(updated[i:i+1], old[i:]...)...)
            report[i] = "*" + report[i]
        }
    }

    // remove elements of the old list that aren't present in the updated
    shifts = diffs(updated, old) // reversed
    n := 0
    for i, d := range shifts {
        if !d.isNew {
            old[n] = old[i]
            n++
        }
    }
    old = old[:n]

    // until lists are identical
    shifts = diffs(old, updated)
    for hasShifts(shifts) {
        // find an element with the largest shift
        highest := 0
        for i, d := range shifts {
            if d.shift > shifts[highest].shift || (d.shift == shifts[highest].shift && d.direction == up) {
                highest = i
            }
        }

        // mark in report how this element shifted
        if shifts[highest].direction == up {
            report[highest] = "↑" + report[highest]
        } else {
            report[highest] = "↓" + report[highest]
        }

        // move this element in the old list to its updated place
        for i, oldEl := range old {
            if oldEl == updated[highest] {
                move(&old, i, shifts[highest].shift, shifts[highest].direction)
                break
            }
        }

        // update diffs
        shifts = diffs(old, updated)
    }
    return
}
```

The function `compare(old, updated)` returns a list of strings that illustrates changes between the two lists in the following manner:

- it has the same order and composition as the updated list;
- a prefix "*" is added to all new elements of the updated list;
- a prefix "↑" is added to elements that need to be shifted up (towards the beginning of the list) to transform the old list into the updated one;
- a prefix "↓" is added to elements that need to be shifted down;
- it prioritizes "up" shifts (if two neighboring elements switched positions).

Let's use the following lists to test it:

```golang
var (
    old = []string{
        "first",
        "second",
        "third",
        "fourth",
        "fifth",
        "sixth",
        "seventh",
        "eighth",
        "ninth",
        "tenth",
    }
    updated = []string{
        "eighth",
        "second",
        "third",
        "first",
        "fourth",
        "new",
        "sixth",
        "seventh",
        "tenth",
        "ninth",
    }
)
```

The result will be:

```
↑eighth
second
third
↓first
fourth
*new
sixth
seventh
↑tenth
ninth
```

Here's a working [go playground example](https://play.golang.org/p/TWb0iTN3_0y).

I am pretty sure it's far from perfect but it will certainly do what I need.